# iOS : 'MyViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

- I am new to `IOS` `swift` development. I used to work with previous `Xcode 6 beta`.
- I have downloaded the `Xcode 6.0.1` and I can not get this to work `Xcode Version: 6.0.1`
- I am still getting "'`MyViewController`' does not confirm to protocol '`UITableViewDataSource`' " when I try to run the example.

Can someone please help me?  I have gone through other issues on this site and added all the required functions for "`UITableViewDataSource`";

---

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{

var array1:[String] = ["one","two","three","four"]

    var array2:[String] = ["IOS","Android","java","c++","Swift"]

    let sectionCount = 2

    var myTableView:UITableView!

    //    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    //        var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 320)
    //        myTableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
    //        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    //        // Custom initialization
    //    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)
        myTableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
        myTableView!.delegate = self
        myTableView!.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //dataSourrce
    //tableview：tableview，section：
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        switch section{
        case 0:
            return array1.count
        case 1:
            return array2.count
        default:
            return 1
        }

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{

        //－－－cellstart－－－－
        let identifier = "identifier"
        //        var cell:UITableViewCell
        //cell
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MyCell
        if cell == nil {
            //            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = MyCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }
        //－－－cellend－－－－

        switch indexPath.section{
        case 0:
            //            cell!.textLabel.text = array1[indexPath.row]
            cell!.myLable!.text = array1[indexPath.row]
        case 1:
            //            cell!.textLabel.text = array2[indexPath.row]
            cell!.myLable!.text = array2[indexPath.row]
        default:
            println()
        }
        var image = UIImage(named: "images/qq.png")
        //        cell!.imageView.image = image
        cell!.myImageView!.image = image
        //        cell!.detailTextLabel.text = "\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)
        return cell!
    }

  //dataSourrce
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        return sectionCount
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var title:String? = nil
        switch section {
        case 0:
            title = "Num"
        case 1:
            title = "Prog"
        default:
            title = nil
        }
        return title
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("Test\(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row)")
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }



    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {}

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!,numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{}

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    }

}
```

***************** My Cell Class ***********************************

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    let indetifier:String = "indetifier"


    var myLable:UILabel?


    var myImageView:UIImageView?

        override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
        {
        super.init(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: indetifier)

        var rect = CGRectMake(10, 0, 60, 30)
        self.myLable = UILabel()
        self.myLable!.frame = rect
        self.myLable!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.myLable!)

        var imageRect = CGRectMake(160, 10, 40, 40)
        self.myImageView = UIImageView()
        self.myImageView!.frame = imageRect
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.myImageView!)


    }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
}
```

Comment: In your numberOfRowsInSection method (and pretty much all your other delegate/datasource methods), UITableView shouldn't be an implicitly unwrapped optional. This changed at some point between Xcode releases. You should keep up to date on the changes by reading the release notes with each new version.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by  "UITableView shouldn't be an implicitly unwrapped optional."  would you be able to correct the above code if possible ?

Comment: Please see page 83 of Apple's book on Swift. Optionals are an elemental part of the language and you need to understand how they work.

Comment: Hi There,
I am not understanding "Optionals are an elemental part" on page 83 :(.

Comment: Sorry, I had my iBooks app opened showing double pages. The full description starts on page 79 under the title, "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals."

Comment: it will be helpful if you can correct the above code, I can read the book while checking your correction.

Comment: His point is that optionals are a very important part of Swift that you *must* know and understand before you can use the language.  Especially when integrating with Objective-C.  You need to go back and read and understand the whole book.

Comment: Hi Sorry,I still can not get it to work :(. I am trying to understand the optionals stuff. I am very new to IOS and Swift and having hard time fixing above to code :(. Can someone help me fix above code....????

Comment: All I was doing the right except, putting all the datasource/delegate methods out of the last 'class' bracket. It feel bit difficult shifting from Objective-C to Swift. :-)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to look at the whole error message.  This specific message includes additional information about which methods are missing:

```
Type 'MyViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'
Protocol requires function 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' with type '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int'
Candidate has non-matching type '(UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int'
```

So... your `numberOfRowsInSection` takes an optional `UITableView`, and should take a *required* `UITableView` (this is a change they made between 6 and 6.1, all `UITableView` delegate and datasource methods now take required `tableView` and `indexPath` values)

Answer (score 13):

### Try this simple solution:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    //MARK: - Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //MARK: - Tableview Delegate & Datasource
    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

```
class ROTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")

//        cell.text = "Row #\(indexPath.row)"
//        cell.detailTextLabel.text = "Subtitle #\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}
```

When you create the subclass for `UITableView` please refer the above code, you will not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i named my `UITableView` as `tableView`. That caused this same error:

> 'MyViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'UITableViewDataSource'

including another error:

> Candidate is not a function

And changed `tableview` name to something else, error is gone.