# swift UITableViewDataSource xcode 6.1

Tags: uitableview, swift, datasource

I'm trying to use UITableViewDataSource in my application.But when I add to UITableViewDataSource to viewControllerClass

This is my code

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource{
```

And there is error what I am getting
     'SecondViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

```
self.messageTableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessageCell")
            self.messageTableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
            self.messageTableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
            self.messageTableView!.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
            self.view.addSubview(self.messageTableView!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reconstructed your code except for the custom message cell and it compiled. I noticed that the improper use of ! in the two required functions for the UITableView will give that message. If you click on the error message (marked in red) it will display additional error messages in the lines causing the problem. Start by removing the ! and sometimes the compile will provide a correctionI also saw on another stack overflow that there was change between 6 and 6.1. I am using 6.1. ([[iOS : 'MyViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935848/myviewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource]))

```
 class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var messages = ["A", "B", "C"]
        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView!.dataSource = self
            tableView!.delegate = self
            self.tableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessageCell")
            self.tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
            self.tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
            self.tableView!.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
            self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            return messages.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {

            var cell:UITableViewCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as UITableViewCell
            var msg=self.messages[indexPath.row]
            //cell.configureWithMessage(msg)
            return cell 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the non optional functions of the protocol, which are:

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: I edit the post a few minutes ago.Its show where I am calling UITableDataSource in my code. What I am doing wrong

Comment: Did you implemented those two functions, that I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes,I did. func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return messages.count
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath! ) -> UITableViewCell!{
        var cell:MessageCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as MessageCell
        var msg=self.messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureWithMessage(msg)
        return cell
    }

Comment: self.messageTableView!.dataSource=self
'SecondViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: What is the declaration of messageTableView ?

Comment: var messageTableView: UITableView?

Comment: so do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if self refers to SecondViewController and you implemented both the methods that I mentioned that what could be the problem.